# Transparent menu/navigation bar

Tags: css

I cannot solve a css problem.

I have a nav bar which should be transparent. But the links on it also get transparent due to the opacity attribute and because they are child elements of the transparent navigation bar.

can u help me to solve this?

Comment: Can you please provide the code example in here or through pastebin so we can better help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kCQ7L/

Comment: Modify your .container class rule

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you dont want your link text to be affected you should modify the rule for the **.container** selector to look like this

```
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 90px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

it will keep your background color design without affecting your text
Opacity , as well said here several times , affect the element and its children

Using opacity . Text is affected

[image]

Using  rgba(255,255,255,0.5), children not affected

[image]

Take care of the other rules that can take action due your javascript and hover situations
Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/qBnHE/)
Bis spater

Comment: what is the compatibility of this method .. ??

Answer (score 7):

The solution is easy. Just set the `background-color` CSS property to `transparent`.

```
.nav {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In css3 you can use transparent backgrounds instead of making the whole panel transparent.

To add a transparent color you can do: `rgba(255,255,255,.5)` where the .5 is the opacity.

Answer (score 1):

You should try just a simple css background property.

```
.navbar
{
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its as simple as this 
background: none;