# How can I make transparent header of site

Tags: header, transparent

How can I create a transparent menu of the site similar to http://zephyr.us-themes.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transparent menu/navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162259/transparent-menu-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css for this by changing the opacity of the html element,

```
   header {
      opacity: 0.5;
      filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
   }
```

The opacity property you can take a value from 0.0 - 1.0. 
  The lower value, makes the html element more 
  transparent.

Please refer below link for further details.
    https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp